# Azure: Run Stored procedure from mobile services

Tags: azure

I am trying to run a schedule task on my db in Azure.
I was reading that this should be done using the mobile-services in the portal - 
So I created a mobile service and created a script which should be run every 1 minute and execute the following script:

```
Job_Sp_CheckOffers();

function Job_Sp_CheckOffers() {    
   var sql = "exec [dbo].[Job.CheckOffers]"; 
   mssql.query(sql);

}
```

Buy it does not affect the db.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After checking the logs of the mobile-service I realized that I need to give the stored procedure a public permissions. I run this on my db:

```
GRANT EXEC ON [Job.IsOfferExpired] TO PUBLIC
```